# Implementing pipe in my own shell with two child process

Tags: c, linux, shell, fork, pipe

I'm writing my own shell. Below is part of it. I want to implement pipe with two child processes.
But when I execute below code, some commands work, some don't. 'who | sort', 'ls | sort' work but 'll | sort', 'cat file | sort' make my shell stop. I have to 'cntrl + c' to escape from my shell. I don't understand why some commands work and some don't. Please somebody point out what I'm missing?

```
int pipefd[2];
int pipePos = checkPipePos(argc, argv); //find '|' command position in argv

if (pipe(pipefd) == -1) {
        printf("Creating pipe failed\n");
        return;
    }

    if (fork() == 0) {
        close(pipefd[0]);
        dup2(pipefd[1], 1);
        execlp(argv[0], argv[0], NULL);
    }

    if (fork() == 0) {
        close(pipefd[1]);
        dup2(pipefd[0], 0);
        execlp(argv[pipePos + 1], argv[pipePos + 1], NULL);
    }

    close(pipefd[0]);
    close(pipefd[1]);

    while (wait(NULL) >= 0);
```

Comment: Is `ll` aliased to `ls -al`?

Comment: Yes, right. Does it affect in this case??.. 'ls | sort' also works,,

Comment: I think you might be using `execlp` wrong. Shouldn't the first argument be a path? https://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/sasc/doc/lr2/execlp.htm

Comment: I thought bash automatically find the path if I put arg in the first argument place. Am I wrong? if yes, how can I fix it?

Comment: Bash can't do anything within your program. Once it begins execution of your program, you are no longer using bash anymore, you're using your shell.

Answer (score 1):

I see one possible problem here, which may or may not explain the non-deterministic results.

In your child process, after you're dup-ing one of the pipe's file descriptor, you're not closing the original ones.

`dup2(oldfd, newfd)` duplicates `oldfd` onto `newfd`, but `oldfd` is still open. Both `oldfd` and `newfd` file descriptors now point to the same file. See the dup2 man page.

Typically, aftering dup2()-ing a file descriptor, you'll want to close() the `oldfd`.

So, what's going to happen here is that one of the child processes will have the same file descriptor on `stdout` and on some other, random file descriptor, and the other child process will have the same situation with `stdin`.

This may or may not cause a problem, depending on what the child process does. Can't really say for sure, but you'll definitely want to fix this, and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your pipe logic is correct.

`ll | sort` doesn't work because `ll` is not a executable file.

`cat file | sort` doesn't work because you are not passing the `file` argument.

Sam Varshavchik's improvement is valid. It's a good-to-fix, but it won't cause any serious problem. All it causes is wasting one more file descriptor slot.

Comment: It's good to print an error message after `execlp()`, in case it fails.